# When to use EXTERNDEF with ABS in MASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

**EXTERNDEF**

Defines one or more external variables, labels, or symbols called *name* whose type is *type*.

**Syntax**

> EXTERNDEF *name:type*

If *name* is defined in the module, it is treated as PUBLIC. If name is referenced in the module, it is treated as EXTERN. If name is not referenced, it is ignored. The *type* can be **ABS**, which imports name as a constant. Normally used in include files.

**QUESTION**

When a MASM global constant

```
NUMBER EQU 12345
```

needs to be shared between assembly files, should it be added to an include file as

```
EXTERNDEF NUMBER:ABS
```

or should the constant itself be moved into the include file?

Both approaches build correctly but which is the preferred method?

**EXAMPLE**

Declare the global constant in this include file

**num.inc**

```
EXTERNDEF NUMBER:ABS
```

The constant is defined in this assembly file

**num.asm**

```
option casemap:none

include num.inc

NUMBER EQU 12345  ; Decided to define here (not moved to num.inc)

.code

DoStuff proc
mov rax,NUMBER
ret  
DoStuff endp

end
```

and is also referenced in this assembly file

**abs.asm**

```
option casemap:none

include num.inc

.code

main proc
mov rax,NUMBER
ret
main endp

end
```

Assembled using this batch file

**abs.bat**

```
@echo on

if not defined DevEnvDir (
  call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
)

ml64.exe abs.asm num.asm /link /subsystem:console /defaultlib:kernel32.lib /defaultlib:libcmt.lib
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer in this book *The Art of 64-Bit Assembly, Volume 1 x86-64 Machine Organization and Programming (Randall Hyde)*, it states the following about the ABS usage:

MASM actually has two external symbol declaration directives: extern
and externdef.

These two directives use the syntax

```
extern symbol:type {optional_list_of_symbol:type_pairs}<br>
externdef symbol:type {optional_list_of_symbol:type_pairs}
```

where symbol is the identifier you want to use from another assembly unit,
and type is the data type of that symbol. The data type can be any of the
following:

- proc, which indicates that the symbol is a procedure (function) name
  or a statement label
- Any MASM built-in data type (such as byte, word, dword, qword, oword, and
  so on)
- Any user-defined data type (such as a struct name)
- **abs**, which indicates a constant value

The **abs** type isn’t for declaring generic external constants such as
someConst = 0. Pure constant declarations, such as this one, would normally
appear in a header file (an include file), which this section will describe
shortly. Instead, the **abs** type is generally reserved for constants that are
based on code offsets within an object module. For example, if you have the
following code in an assembly unit,

```
        public someLen
someStr byte   "abcdefg"
someLen =      $-someStr
```

someLen’s type, in an extern declaration, would be **abs**.